# How to find directions through google map in ios?

Tags: iphone

I have searched but i did not get what i wanted.

I am developing an application in which i want to give give location names from my application and

call the google map to show the directions. what url i need to write to find the directions

Kindly help.

Please get back to me for any clarifications...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting driving directions is not part of the IOS Mapkit framework. Use Google map APi for the purpose. I think this may help you

```
 https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=cochin&daddr={destination_address}
```

Example

```
 http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=San+Francisco,+CA&saddr=cupertino
```

Please refer the link from apple developer site [here](http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=San%20Francisco,%20CA&saddr=cupertino) too.

You can form the URL as

```
Nsstring * startLocation = @"Mumbai";
NSString * endLocation = @"Delhi";

 NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:"https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%@&daddr=%@",startLocation,endLocation];
NSURL * url = [NSURL urlWithString:urlString];
```

Comment: ya ,i got ,i am new to ios but how will i pass the values in the url if it is a string as i have tried eg: a=india,b=america.. then my url would be ..http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%s&daddr=%s&hl=en",a,b.....giving an error ,please guide

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is this,

https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/MapKit-Route-Directions